# Getting response like this after giving delete request in postman "" null"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

Below is the code which I wrote for the delete request:-

```
exports.deletedepartment = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const result= await Department.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id});
        res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message:err});
    }
}
```

*Postman response:*

[image: click the link you will see postman respone]

Comment: Have you tried `const result= await Department.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);`?  [`findByIdAndRemove(id, ...)`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove)  is equivalent to `findOneAndRemove({ _id: id }, ...)`.

Comment: I don't know if you've seen it but you send a `Get` request with postman, not a `Del`

Comment: @MikeGerard what if I want to remove that document from collection ???